# appcelerator titanium cannot parse JSON

Tags: json, titanium, appcelerator

I'm new to titanium and get difficulty in parsing JSON from mysql export. the json is valid and I feel frustrated with many unsuccessful trials. To simplify the code, I put it below. The code just stop and said:
[ERROR] Script Error = Unable to parse JSON string

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;


var hotdealjson = "{'hotdeal':[{'place':'bangkok','date':'4D3N','cost':'$4999up'},{'place':'tokyo','date':'3D2N','cost':'$3799up'}]}";


//read json
var response = JSON.parse(hotdealjson);
alert(response.hotdeal.length);
```

Thanks & regards,
Richard

Answer (score 5):

The JSON is actually invalid. The single quotes should be double quotes.

A very common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me:

var object = eval('(' + json_text + ')');

That's from the Kitchen Sink, and I've seen that evaluation style advocated in a Javascript text.

Comment: watch out.. eval is a dangerous way of deserializing json.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to check the JSON validity before using/parsing anywhere! Use the [JSONLint - The JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/) for the same.

Comment: I am not getting why someone needs to rate down the answer even though it's correct! At first sight I found the @Richard's JSON string invalid and that's the reason I suggest him to use JSON validator!